# How do I get a D-link DWA 140 working?

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I've created a bootable usb stick, under windows, and checked the disk is OK.
Load the try Ubuntu option and, as with 11.04 and 11.10, it can't find the D-Link adaptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems driver for this USB wifi adapter doesn't work "out of the box" as said on the official Ubuntu support page. Check this guide: http://luismi.sanchezarteaga.es/instalacion-de-d-link-wifi-usb-dwa-140b3-en-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

It's in spanish but commands worked fine for me.
Regards.